# Async Sockets in C# - Knowing your clients

Tags: c#, sockets, asynchronous, client-server

I'm sure this has a simple work around, but right now I seem to have the inability to find an elegant solution. I have built an ASync C# server application which accepts multiple clients and handles them well, but to proceed I need to be able to determine which clients are connected to my server (there will be only two clients both of which do different things).

When my program accepts these clients I want the server to know the clients address and an indication which client is which potentially stored in a small list.

So I guess what I'm asking, is there a simple means of when the client has connected, sending a predefined message to the server letting it know what client application goes to which address?

Thanks

Comment: Are you talking about identifying the client for internal uses, or do you mean you don't know from which client for example an `EndReceive()` comes? If the latter is the case: use a state object (`IAsyncResult.AsyncState`), containing your client class containing the connected socket which you provide when you call `BeginReceive()`.

Comment: For internal uses, thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 1):

There are numerous ways.

One of the easiest is to have a different port for each of the client applications. The other way is in order to "connect" (after TCP Handshake) is to send a message identifying the application before any data is exchanged. The other option would be to add headers to each requests / reply stating the application and storing that.

Answer (score 1):

You are free to send all kind of data over sockets.

To solve this, invent some kind of protocol between client and server.

For instance sending a first message when connecting to identify the client to the server.
From there on continue with the normal conversation between those two.

Server can accept the message and store of show it, or even reject the client when the first message does not contain the agreed information.